# How to delete a run_id from MLflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, mlflow, mlops

I want to permanently delete a `run_id` from an experiment in `MLflow`

I am using the following code:

```
import mlflow
from mlflow.entities import ViewType
_mlflow_tracking_uri = "the mlflow tracking url"
exp_id_delete = "2"
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(_mlflow_tracking_uri)
           

client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()
run_infos = mlflow.list_run_infos(exp_id_delete, run_view_type=ViewType.DELETED_ONLY)
               
for r in run_infos:
                    
   client.delete_run(r.run_id)
```

But I get an error `INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: The run blabla must be in the 'active' state. Current state is deleted.`

Any ideas ?

*UPDATE*

I tried writing some code with the help of the link that @Alex Ott suggested:

```
import mlflow
from mlflow.entities import ViewType
from mlflow.store.tracking import DEFAULT_LOCAL_FILE_AND_ARTIFACT_PATH
from mlflow.store.artifact.artifact_repository_registry import get_artifact_repository
from mlflow.tracking import _get_store
from mlflow.entities.lifecycle_stage import LifecycleStage
from mlflow.exceptions import MlflowException
_mlflow_tracking_uri = "the mlflow tracking url"
exp_id_delete = "2"
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(_mlflow_tracking_uri)


client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()
run_infos = mlflow.list_run_infos(exp_id_delete, run_view_type=ViewType.DELETED_ONLY)

for r in run_infos:
      

 print("- run_id: {}, lifecycle_stage: {}".format(r.run_id, r.lifecycle_stage))

 run = backend_store.get_run(r.run_id)
 if run.info.lifecycle_stage != LifecycleStage.DELETED:
      raise MlflowException(
          "Run % is not in `deleted` lifecycle stage. Only runs in "
          "`deleted` lifecycle stage can be deleted." % r.run_id
                    )
 artifact_repo = get_artifact_repository(run.info.artifact_uri)
 artifact_repo.delete_artifacts()
 backend_store._hard_delete_run(r.run_id)
 print("Run with ID %s has been permanently deleted." % str(r.run_id))
```

But now, even though I get as first message:

```
 Deleted runs: run_id: 24ac591d1af840cfb703131dbe1f92a9, lifecycle_stage: deleted
```

then I get the following error

```
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Run '24ac591d1af840cfb703131dbe1f92a9' not found
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`mlflow gc` command](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-gc) for that - potentially you can call it from your Python script, or at least do the same as in the [source code](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/cli.py#L425).

Comment: where do you need to run this mlflow gc command ?

Comment: Do you mean, there is a command line tool in the mlflow UI ?

Comment: How do you run MLflow? What backend is used?

Comment: I spin up the application through a python script and then I visit the `_mlflow_tracking_uri` via the browser

Comment: but what is used as backend? is it files on the disk backend? Show how do you execute MLflow - what parameters are specified etc

Comment: `_mlflow_tracking_uri = "a url"`
 `mlflow.set_tracking_uri(_mlflow_tracking_uri)`
`mlflow.set_experiment("experiment name")`
`client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()`

thats how I execute it, and in the backend some artifacts are save (model results, csvs pngs etc)